# Use colored text for badge counts instead of badge logos

Tags: discussion, design, badges, user-interface

I was looking at some posts by users with many thousands of badges, and I noticed that there were two lines required for displaying the badges. This was caused by the badge icons (●). Should we remove the badge icons and replace them with colored numbers? I feel this would be an improvement to the current UI of the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of one reason it's not a good idea: if you take away the color, it's just a bunch of numbers. New users who are color blind will have a hard time digesting "37,911 14 85 170" (my current stats on this site); it's a bit easier to grasp with dots in between.

What we *can* do is rounding; e.g. [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s Stack Overflow posts currently show "1055k ● 651 ● 7758 ● 8312" but "1.1M ● 651 ● 7.8k ● 8.3k" conveys the same information and is short enough to fit on one line:

[image]

But, really. Jon (and others) have put so much time and energy into Stack Exchange, they have *earned* that extra line.